# Why does list-style-type not work ? Nothing was shown instead

Tags: html, css

CSS and HTML Code is as shown below. I used eric meyer's reset script.. I edited out the one which I think is relevant.

```
    /* reset CSS script */

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/* End of reset CSS script */

#navbar {
    border: 5px solid red;
    margin: -580px 0 0 160px;
    width: 1500px; 

    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: 'Conv_LITHOSPRO-REGULAR';
}
#navbar ul li {     
        display:inline;
        padding:0 35px 0 0; 
        list-style-type:disc;
        }
```

This is the HTML code.

```
        <nav id="navbar">
            <ul id="hli">
                <li id="OP"><a  href="Orders.html">Your Order</a></li>
                <li id="MP"><a  href="Menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                <li id="CUP"><a  href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li id="JP"><a  href="Jobs.html" target="_blank">Jobs</a></li>
                <li id="TCP"><a  href="TC.html">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </nav>
```

Comment: Because `li { display: inline }`.

Comment: Oh thanks a bunch. I didn't know    display:inline conflicts with    list-style-image .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`list-style-type` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-list-style-type) applies to elements with `display: list-item` only. So if you want to put some markers before list items that you have turned to inline elements, you have to add markers into the content directly, or via generated content. E.g., the following puts a bullet “•” and a space before each item:

```css
#navbar ul li:before {
   content: "\2022  "
}
```

Comment: Hmm good to know. Will try this out.. On a sidenote, does 'list-style-position:inside' work ?

Comment: All the `list-style` properties apply to elements with `display: list-item` only.

Comment: Gah! This caught me out too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case overflow-x:hidden caused the problem.